# Hex editor for viewing combined string and float data

Tags: windows, binary, hex, hex-editors

I have a binary file of unknown format that I need to be able to read. I have access to a program which can 'unpack' the file, but the user interface is terrible for exporting data. I've extracted a few points in an attempt to search for them in the file and discover a pattern, but it's not an efficient method.  What I'm trying to do is match hex patterns to single floating point values, but copying, pasting, translating, and searching the file is not a quick process.

I've looked around quite a bit, and I can't seem to find any hex editors that allow a user to highlight 4 or 8 bytes and display a single or double floating point number in the text view, rather than [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Maybe I'm not utilizing the full potential of the hex editors I've tried, but I'm stuck. Here's a list of editors I've tried. Does anyone know of an editor that has the features I need, or how to correctly use the ones I've attempted?

- HEdit
- FlexHex
- Hex Editor NEO
- Notepad++ Hex Plugin
- HxD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime ago, I wrote an Hex viewer called [Serial Wizard](http://serialwizard.sourceforge.net/) which has a functionality like this.

Unfortunately it has only conversions for integral types (integer, long, etc) but it's relatively easy to add new conversions.If you want I can try to write a float converter tomorrow.

Comment: I tried Serial Viewer, and it performs similarly to some of the other hex editors I've tried. It allows highlighting byte groups and temporarily displaying numerical values. What I was looking for is the ability to highlight a series of bytes and permanently change the way the program displays them in the string view. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: *Serial Wizard, not Serial Viewer... apparently I didn't have enough coffee this morning

Comment: np. Actually it may be possible to achieve something like that using "protocol handlers" (the name is misleading)