# Reading hexdump: integers and reals

Tags: hex, hex-editors

I wanted to know the structure of an unknown binary file generated by Fortran routine. For the same I downloaded hex editor. I am fairly new to the whole concept. I can see some character strings in the conversion tool. However, the rest is just dots and junk characters.

I tried with some online converter but it only converts to the decimal systems. Is there any possible way to figure out that certain hex represents integer and real?

I also referred to following thread, but I couldn't get much out of it.
[Hex editor for viewing combined string and float data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993656/hex-editor-for-viewing-combined-string-and-float-data?rq=1)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What platform/OS are you on?

Comment: I am using sun solaris KDE, however, to inspect the file and have more flexibility, i moved it to my windows 7 pc. Since the system is from 90s, even fortran compiler does not support stream access and many new functionalities which were introduced in later versions of fortran.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. If you really know nothing of the format, then you are stuck. You might see some "obvious" text, in some language, but beyond that, it's pretty much impossible. Your Hex editor reads the file as a group of bytes, and displays, usually, ASCII equivalents beside the hex values. If a byte is not a printable ASCII character, it usually displays a .

So, text aside, if you see a value $31 in the file, you have no way of knowing if this represents a single character ('1'), or is part of a 2 byte word, or a 4 byte long, or indeed an 8 byte floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

In general, that is going to be pretty hard! Some of the following ideas may help.

1. Can you give the FORTRAN program some inputs that make it change the length/amount of output data? E.g. can you make it produce 1 unit of output, then 8 units of output, then 64 units of output - by `unit` I mean the number of values it outputs if that is what it does. If so, you can plot output file length against number of units of output and the intercept will tell you how many bytes the header is, if any. So, for example, if you can make it produce one number and you get an output file that is 24 bytes long, and when you make it produce 2 numbers the output file is 28 bytes long, you might deduce that there is a 20 byte header at the start and then 4 bytes per number.
2. Can you generate some known output? E.g. Can you make it produce zero, or 256 as an output, if so, you can search for zeroes and `FF` in your output file and see if you can locate them.
3. Make it generate a zero (or some other number) and save the output file, then make it generate a one (or some other, different number) and save the output file, then difference the files to deduce where that number is located. Or just make it produce any two different numbers and see how much of the output file changes.
4. Do you have another program that can understand the file? Or some way of knowing any numbers in the file? If so, get those numbers and convert them into hex and look for their positions in the hex dump.

Comment: The file binary file is fairly complex with integer*2, integer*4, real and characters. However, from the Fortran scripts I managed to filter out the header of the file. Also header is of variable size, depending upon the number of data-type are given by the user. I know, it's a strenuous task. I am gonna try as you have suggested anyway!